# DELPHI MSBuild and *.optset file

Tags: delphi, jenkins

We use DELPHI 10.4 and MSBuild on a JENKINS slave for CI  within our projects.

As the paths to *.exe output, search folder, ....   in the given *.dproj on our local clients are different on the JENKINS slave we use *.optset files with paths adjusted to the Jenkins slave.
This strategy seems to work nicely except for some project where it seems that the compilation is only based on the *.dproj settings.

To ensure the use of an options file we add to the *.dproj the following statement

```
<Import Condition="Exists('$(OptSet)')" Project="$(OptSet)"/>
```

But this seems to fail sometimes.
Q:   how to force the usage of the *.optset file, how to handle the compilation on different systems with MSBuild - some very flexible replacements for path settings.

Comment: I use only relative paths in my projects and never had any problems on different build environments.

Comment: is there any smart way to change existing *.droj  to relative paths ?

Comment: You could write a little tool that manipulates XML data ...